# Using an Array of values with a Match Expression in PHP

Tags: php, match, php-8

Is there a way to use an array as a list of values to match against in a [`match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) expression in PHP?

Consider this:

```
return match ($field) {
    'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'updated_at', 'created_at' => (string) $item->{$field},
    'image' => $item->{$field}->getUrls(),
    'balance' => (int) $item->{$field},
    default => null
};
```

Whilst the above works, I would like to format the match statement in a more readable/manageable manner. For instance, I use the above expression on my data transformers for presenting data in my APIs; as such, I can find myself in situations where there are many fields returned in one format, and it would be significantly more readable to present it in the following manner (or something similar):

```
$string_columns = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'updated_at', 'created_at'];

return match ($field) {
    $string_columns => (string) $item->{$field},
    'image'         => $item->{$field}->getUrls(),
    'balance'       => (int) $item->{$field},
    default         => null
};
```

Comment: Not sure if you knew that, but you don't need curly braces for `$item->{$field}` - it will work just fine as `$item->$field`

Comment: @RoboRobok - ah, I didn't kmow that... Is that new in PHP 8? If not, not sure why I had those there in the first place

Comment: Nah, I've been doing it like that for ages :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question inspired me to check if `...$string_columns` would work for `match` statement, but it doesn't.

I don't think there's any way to do it with `match`, other than tricks.

One trick I thought of was to create a helper function to return the value only if it's in the array:

```php
function any(array $values, $value)
{
    return in_array($value, $values, true) ? $value : null;
}

$string_columns = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'updated_at', 'created_at'];

return match ($field) {
    any($string_columns, $field) => (string) $item->{$field},
    'image'                      => $item->{$field}->getUrls(),
    'balance'                    => (int) $item->{$field},
    default                      => null
};
```

A bit verbose, but would work.

I think it's worth to understand `match` as a language construction that suits only certain scenarios.

Comment: This code will broke witch $field==null - it will try $item->{null}; BTW, ...$array in match will be nice

Comment: Of course it will break with null, but you wouldn't use it with null.

Comment: I agree, I have tried various things and it does seem that this isn't possible without a slightly dirty workaround. I'll mark this one as the accepted answer simply because you posted it first. Both answers are creative, and to be honest, I don't really have a preference for either. That being said, I guess I could extract this to a global helper function and then utilise it anywhere in that I need it, whereas the other answer, this would not be possible. Thank you :-D

Comment: @BenCarey my pleasure and thank you for choosing my answer. I wonder if `...$array` will work at some point. PHP 8.1, maybe?

Comment: @RoboRobok - one would hope, it seems fairly self-explanatory...

Comment: @Rain no offence, but your reasoning doesn't make any sense to me here. What same elements? Unpacking has a lot of meanings, see what you can do with it in JavaScript, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not posible. Just add in_array in default value.

```php
return match ($field) {
    'image'         => $item->{$field}->getUrls(),
    'balance'       => (int) $item->{$field},
    default => in_array($value, $string_columns, true) ? 
              (string) $item->{$field} 
              : null;
};
```

If there will be more arrays, you can chain ternary operator

Comment: You'd probably want to remove the `$string_columns => (string) $item->{$field},`

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I have accepted the other one simply because it was posted first, and because it can technically be reused throughout the project, whereas this one can only be used once per match expression which is not ideal